# @Autowired vs @PersistenceContext for EntityManager bean

Tags: spring, jpa, entitymanager

What is the difference between:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
```

versus:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Both options work in my application, but can I break something by using the  `@Autowired` annotation?

Answer (score 65):

You shouldn't use `@Autowired`. `@Autowired` normally would create just one bean of `EntityManager` to be used for the entire application. But we need a new `EntityManager` object for every communication (database transaction) with the database. In this communication we can make multiple actions: `inserts, deletes, updates, reads`, which **need to happen under the same context** (the persistence context) isolated from other similar contexts that can happen in the same time.

`@PersistenceContext` takes care to create a unique `EntityManager` for every transaction (communication with the database). In a production application you can have multiple clients calling your application in the same time. For each call, the application will create a new thread, will open/create a new transaction with the database and will assign a separate persistence context. Each thread, in this case, must use its own `EntityManager`.

**Conclusion:**

Please also check the **`ACID`** four key properties of a transaction: atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability. **Conclusion:** The `PersistenceContext` is the `context` for each transaction and makes those four properties be possible.

*Other thread related properties of the EntityManager:*

```
usually the EntityManager or Session are bound to the thread (implemented as a ThreadLocal variable).
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42074452/2623162

```
EntityManager instances are not thread-safe.
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqy/index.html

*Other info related to the @PersistenceContext*

Please notice that `@PersistenceContext` annotation comes from `javax.persistence` package, not from spring framework. In JavaEE it is used by the JavaEE container (aka the application server) to inject the EntityManager. Spring borrowed the PersistenceContext annotation to do the same: to inject an **application-managed** (= not container-managed) EntityManager bean per thread, exactly as the JavaEE container does.

**UPDATE:**

**I updated the answer because it was confusing. Thank you, @silver_mx - his comment bellow**

Comment: I can confirm this when talking about threads. For example, without @PersistenceContext my application runs SQL insert/update in other thread but no changes are made to the database.

Comment: In Spring's context, I do not think this answer is correct. Thread-safety is not an issue according to the documentation (see an answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/74611778/677096). The difference comes down about how to refer to different entity managers (when using multiple datasources), i.e. @PersistentContext(name = "emBeanName") or @Qualifier("emBeanName")@Autowired. Spring normally injects a proxy that handles threading issues as far as I have seen.

Comment: @silver_mx: I updated the answer to check also your comment, thank you

Comment: @silver_mx: I refactored the answer because it was really confusing, thank you very much

Answer (score 42):

`@PersistenceContext` allows you to specify which persistence unit you want to use. Your project might have multiple data sources connected to different DBs and `@PersistenceContext` allows you to say which one you want to operate on

check the explanation here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/481448/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/unitName-PersistenceContext

Answer (score 32):

**@PersistenceContext**:

**does not** return entity manager instance

**it returns** container-managed proxy that acquires and releases presistence context on behalf of the application code

Answer (score 18):

`@PersistenceContext` is a [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) standard annotation designed for that specific purpose. Whereas `@Autowired` is used for any dependency injection in Spring. Using `@PersistenceContext` gives you greater control over your context as it provides you with ability to specify optional elements e.g. name, properties

Comment: I know this, but what is  the  impact in the  application? Consider using the standard **@Transactional** from Spring. When using the **@Autowired**, the same behaviour as using **@PersistenceContext** will occur and have the em per application transaction?

Comment: I believe it is typically best practice to use `@PersistenceContext` as it more closely describes the type of dependency injection you are trying to achieve. In addition it provides optional parameters specifically for the use of a EntityManager, this can be useful when you have more than one EntityManager. Functionally I believe you could achieve the same injection with `@Autowired`, but I would recommened using the annotation designed to be used like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Autowire will work same way as @PersistenceContext

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.misc.jpa-context

> When working with multiple EntityManager instances and custom
> repository implementations, you need to wire the correct EntityManager
> into the repository implementation class. You can do so by explicitly
> naming the EntityManager in the @PersistenceContext annotation or, if
> the EntityManager is @Autowired, by using @Qualifier.
>
> As of Spring Data JPA 1.9, Spring Data JPA includes a class called
> JpaContext that lets you obtain the EntityManager by managed domain
> class, assuming it is managed by only one of the EntityManager
> instances in the application. The following example shows how to use
> JpaContext in a custom repository:

Answer (score 1):

Info from Spring team on how to use `@Autowired` with `Entity manager` provided [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15076#issuecomment-1634307435).

**The recommendations are:**

For the time being, a plain Spring application can define a bean of type `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean`, wiring it to a specific `EntityManagerFactory`, potentially defining a qualifier on it (e.g. the persistence unit name) - and then injecting it via `@Autowired` and the common qualifier mechanism if necessary, or simply through a plain constructor argument.

Due to the separate nature of the shared `EntityManager` instance, there is no first-class mechanism to do so implicitly. An explicit `SharedEntityManagerBean` is a straightforward FactoryBean matched by type and does not require additional post-processors. Alternatively, you could declare an `@Bean` method which returns an `EntityManager` built through `SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager`, not even involving a FactoryBean then:

```java
@Bean
public EntityManager sharedEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(emf);
}
```

That's essentially what Spring Data JPA's post-processor ends up registering as well. If there is nothing else we can do at the core Spring Framework level, maybe we should explicitly show the approach above in the reference documentation.

Answer (score -3):

You can create the following `FactoryBean` to make `EntityManager` properly injectable, even via constructor injection:

```
/**
 * Makes the {@link EntityManager} injectable via <i>@Autowired</i>,
 * so it can be injected with constructor injection too.
 * (<i>@PersistenceContext</i> cannot be used for constructor injection.)
 */
public static class EntityManagerInjectionFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<EntityManager> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return EntityManager.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager createInstance() {
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

Please note, that because we use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation internally, the returned `EntityManager` will be a proper thread-safe proxy, as it would have been injected directly at the place of usage with field injection (using `@PersistenceContext`).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `entityManager` variable in your factory will only be injected once, and your factory probably only has one instance which means every `createInstance()` calling will return the same `EntityManager`. So it is a totally useless wrapper.