# What is the difference between annotating EntityManager with @Autowired and @PersistenceContext? Which one should be preferred?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a Spring-Boot application using [spring-boot-starter-data-jpa](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.5.RELEASE). I am not able to understand which annotation I should use for injecting EntityManager?
`@Autowired` or `@PersistenceContext`

I know `@PersistenceContext` is a JPA annotation whereas `@Autowired` belongs to Spring. But internally how do they make a difference?
I have already taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335211/autowired-vs-persistencecontext-for-entitymanager-bean). But could not understand the exact reason.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335211/autowired-vs-persistencecontext-for-entitymanager-bean

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Yes, its a duplicate and my question's description says that. Let me know if you can help me understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

A datasource is source of data. This could be for example a database.

One option if you need multiple datasources is to define them in a persistence.xml file. Here you can define multiple and separate them by name.

@PersistenceContext will then give you more fine grain of what you want to inject. Here you can select which datasource by defined name. There are some other options too.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html

If using @Autowire you are just injecting the available persistence context by bean name. If you have 2 or more persistence contexts this may fail because of ambiguity.

Comment: Do you have a specific example wherein there are multiple data sources used in Spring Boot and PersistenceContext is used? Also what are the fine grained controls PersistenceContext offers compared to a EntityManager Autowired?

Comment: spring will not load a persistence.xml by default. You have to set it up manually.
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-orm/local-container-entity-manager-factory-bean.html

configuring a persistence.xml is a science: https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-persistence-xml/

Comment: Fine grained settings on @PersistanceContext can for example be defining if the context is transaction managed or extended-managed, which means should it be bound to the transaction or should it be bound to the lifecycle of the bean.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547817/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-scoped-persistence-context-and-extend

Comment: today with microservices you hardly use persistence.xml anymore, its to clunky and verbose.

Comment: if you want to learn about how persistance works in java you should learn the persistance api in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html