# Spring getting entityManger without annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am wondering from where does come this `entityManager` via constructor? Why i do not have to use `@PersistenceContext` annotation below?
Spring creates this bean via `@Repository` annotation.

```
@Repository
public class RRepositoryCustomImpl {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public RRepositoryCustomImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

Second option is using `@PersistenceContext` annotation:

```
@Repository
public class ACustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Why we can define EntityManager without @PersistenceContext annotation in the code example above? What's the difference between this two approaches? From where Spring takes EntityManager in this two scenarios?

Possible duplicate of: [@Autowired vs @PersistenceContext for EntityManager bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335211/autowired-vs-persistencecontext-for-entitymanager-bean)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why we can define EntityManager without `@PersistenceContext` annotation in the code example above? What's the difference between this two approaches? From where Spring takes EntityManager in this two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

the entityManager is marked as Autowired in the constructor, because of that you are able to use it.

Comment: Why we can define EntityManager without @PersistenceContext annotation in the code example above? What's the difference between this two approaches? From where Spring takes EntityManager in this two scenarios?

Comment: You can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335211/autowired-vs-persistencecontext-for-entitymanager-bean