# EntityManager constructor injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, dependency-injection

When using constructor injection, what is the correct way of injecting the persistence context ?

Both of these solution makes my integration test pass, so looks like `EntityManager`
is injected correctly, but I am not sure about the difference.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class StockService {

    private StockRepo stockRepo;
    private IndexRepo indexRepo;
    private EntityManager entityManager;
...
}
```

or

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class StockService {

    private StockRepo stockRepo;
    private IndexRepo indexRepo;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
...
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335211/autowired-vs-persistencecontext-for-entitymanager-bean

Comment: Does not answer if it's possible or not have constructor injection for it ? :)