java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String)" because "this.entity" is null?
[Unable to correctly inject/initialize EntityManger in spring]
I want to GET some records from database after hitting get from frontend in spring but because of entity being null unable to do so.
Error in terminal:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String)" because "this.entity" is null
        at com.rupeedock.pet.dao.DaoIMPL.newExpense(DaoIMPL.java:17) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na] 
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~


Below is the DaoIMPL.java file Code.
package com.rupeedock.pet.dao;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.rupeedock.pet.entity.*;
import com.rupeedock.pet.model.*;

@Repository
public class DaoIMPL implements RupeedockDAO{
@PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entity;

@Override
public ExpenseModel newExpense(ExpenseModel expenseModel)
{
    int id = 1;
    ExpenseEntity present = (ExpenseEntity) entity.createQuery("select c from ExpenseEntity c where c.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .getSingleResult();
ExpenseModel model = new ExpenseModel();
model.setId(present.getId());
model.setDescription(present.getDescription());
model.setAmount(present.getAmount());
System.out.println("Retrieved Description: " + model.getDescription());
return model;
    
}
}


Dependencies added in build.gradle file
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core' // Optional, if session handling needed
    
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    
    //implementation 'javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.3' // Optional, needed for transactions
}

ExpenseEntity.java
package com.rupeedock.pet.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "expenses")
public class ExpenseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String amount;

    // Getters and Setters
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
    public String getAmount() { return amount; }
    public void setAmount(String amount) { this.amount = amount; }
}

GitHub Repo Link of full project
I want to GET some records from database after hitting get from frontend in spring but because of entity being null unable to do so. If Entity gets instantiated correctly I should  be able to see the SOP prints in terminal.

The NPE is because your entiry is not initialized. Is this your problem? If not then update a question to include the problem or error that is relevant to your question

@RomanC entity is expected to be initialized automatically by JPA because of the @PersistenceContext annotation, hence the OP didn't expect it to be null.

@k314159 If it didn't initialized then there should be the cause, the exact cause is required to clarify the problem.

You are using Spring Boot then why not use Spring Data JPA repositories instead? That being said, post thew full stacktrace not some snippet of it and show you you are using the Repository as well. There is too little information here to answer the question (and we aren't going to dig through all your sources in github). But I wouldn't be surprised you would be using Spring Boot 3 and added an old javax.persistence api jar which is incompatible.

Did you tried to replace PersistenceContext by Autowired?

Looking at your GitHub repo, I see you're using Spring Boot 3 and javax.persistence. That's incompatible. You need to replace it with jakarta.persistence (in both your Gradle build file and in your imports).

@talexmovedtoCodidact not a good idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335211/autowired-vs-persistencecontext-for-entitymanager-bean

@k314159 as pointed in comments top answer is wrong for Spring.

@k314159 you were right I was using javax.persistence which is incompatible with Spring 3. Issue is now resolved. Thanks for helping me sir.
